# Polish/Russian city Name from 1912 Manifest

Tags: palaeography, poland, russia, manifest, 1910s

[image]

I'm looking to transcribe a Polish/Russian city name from 1912 Manifest.

I'm excited to have found the right ancestor on a passenger list, but I can't quite make out the name of the city marked as "Last Permanent place of residence".

I'm currently reading the History of Poland by Adam Zamoyski and understand the partitioning, etc. With the dramatic border changes and old handwriting I just need guidance.

I was guessing "Woda Nowa" - and then under "nearest place of friend where Alien came" it's the same address with what I think reads maybe "S. Warsaw". In the census that they were on place of birth is Warsaw - but in my experience when they don't speak English census takers tend to guess or translate wrong.

---

If anyone wants to take a stab at the "fathers" name, by all means. I am assuming that the "father" is the father of his Wife "Marianna Olszewski". My Great Grandmother on my father's side is a bit of a mystery. My Grandmother remembers her mother saying (someone) was a terrible man (husband or 2nd husband after 1st died - or maybe her mother's father) and she'd never use his name in the new world. So her (2nd marriag?/maiden name is a mystery, the woman used 2-3 names and never became a citizen and her kids used to joke the police were coming to deport her some day.

Obviously the last name of the "Father" does not match the name on the ship log which is "Wladislaw Olszewski" which is why i am guessing it's his wife's father's name.

Comment: Hi Erica, the father's name applies to the person on the line below, not Wladislaw.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent resource in which to find the names and descriptions of Polish towns is the [Słownik geograficzny Królestwa Polskiego i innych krajów słowiańskich (Geographic dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland other Slavic countries](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/). I took a look for Wodanowa but did not find anything. Under [Nowawola](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_VII/213), however, there is an entry which is near Warsaw.